# Get text nested within elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have this DOM structure:

```
<span id="aa"><a id="bb">myname</a> test test test</span>
```

I want to be able to select #aa and then split #bb away from the text "test test test" since I need to perform some string operations (replace) with the text. How do I select just the text in this case? And then after the string replace operation, I want to make sure I can merge it back to #bb and within #aa.

Let me know the best way to approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove DOM elements temporarily:

```
$(function () {
  var $aa = $('#aa'),
      $bb = $('#bb');
  $bb.remove(); // remove bb
  $aa.text($aa.text().replace(/test/g, 'replaced')); // text manipulations on aa
  $bb.prependTo($aa); // restore the removed element
});
```

The [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) function removes the element from the DOM, but the elements will still available on the jQuery object, allowing you to use it further.

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ezopa/edit).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly this is what you want to do:

```
var bb = $('#bb');
var foo = bb.clone();
bb.remove();

// ... do whatever you like with #aa here

// restore #bb element
$('#aa').prepend(foo);
```

If you would like to modify the contents of the `#bb` it's even easier:

```
var bb = $('#bb');
var text = bb.text();

// ... do whatever you like with text here

// save new text
bb.text(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contents of bb using $('#bb') and then obtain its contents like so;

```
$bb('#bb').text();
```

Does that answer your q?

See [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes) for more info.